# Why is one geth peer using TCP port 2743?

Tags: go-ethereum

All my other peers look like this (admin.peers)
  remoteAddress: xx.xx.xx.xx:30303

But one peer looks like this:
  remoteAddress: xx.xx.xx.xx:2743

(This port is listed as 'murx protocol', which I have never heard of)

Comment: as long as it's using tcp/udp.

Comment: What if I want to run 2 geth nodes on one machine, one on testnet one on mainnet? Two processes can't share the same port. You don't take the freedom of choosing the port numbers away from people

Answer (score 1):

Nodes can choose the port they run the software on, that's just the port they chose. I have no idea what murx is, but apparently that's the most common use for port 2743.